# How to use is_arithmetic taking an universal reference?

Tags: c++, type-traits, forwarding-reference

Playing with variadic templates I made functions that sums elements.

It works well but I wanted to add a type_trait test to check if all arguments passed are numeric types.

It works if i give r values but it blocks if i give lvalues.

```
    sum.h

#ifndef SUM_H_INCLUDED
#define SUM_H_INCLUDED

#include<type_traits>

template <typename T>
double sums_(T && arg)
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,"Only numbers !");
    return arg;
}

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
double sums_(T && val, Args &&... args)
{
    return sums_(std::forward<T>(val)) + sums_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename ... Args>
double sums(Args &&... args)
{
    return sums_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}


#endif // SUM_H_INCLUDED

    main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "sum.h"


int main()
{

    //works
    std::cout << sums(42.30,28) << std::endl;

    int x = 100;
    //error
    std::cout << sums(42.30,28,x) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It seems normal, since is_arithmetic::value = false for a reference on a numeric type (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic). But, how could I test that my variables are numeric in the case of a universal reference ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
std::is_arithmetic<std::remove_reference_t<T>>
```

since a forwarding reference makes `T` either a reference to a possibly cv-qualified type or a such type itself, and `is_arithmetic` already handles cv-qualifiers.

Comment: Works perfectly . Thanks !